# overload "->" (member access) recursively

Tags: c++

I am learning how to overload "->" and the documentation says that:
"operator-> is called again on the value that it returns, recursively, until the operator-> is reached that returns a plain pointer. After that, builtin semantics are applied to that pointer."

While it is clear what the documentation says, essentially that an overloaded "->" of a class could use itself a "special pointer" having itself an overloaded "->" that could give a "special pointer" etc etc until a "plain pointer" is found, I cannot find an example of a real use of it ( unless it is used to find a linked list last element ).

Could somebody explain what is the retionale behind the scenes, ( as that possibility isn't provided with "plain pointers" - so I dont' see any reason to provide it with "special pointers" ).

An example of real world use could help too, as probably I am missing a model where to apply the behaviour.

On the opposite side there could be the need to avoid that behaviour, how could it be done ?

Comment: Could you please define "plain pointer" and "special pointer"

Comment: I looked up what shared_ptr are, but where is the recursion ?

Comment: "plain pointer" is a "normal pointer" of C++.

Comment: special pointer is a struct ( or class ) where we overload "operator->"

Comment: So you're talking about 'smart pointers' not 'special pointers', which aren't a thing.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode, there are pointer-like things that are not "smart pointers", e.g. iterators, or user-defined pointer types returned from allocators

Comment: Here's a concrete example of a useful chaining if that's what you were searching for: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/157444/22929 . In order to avoid that behavior you have several choices: return something that doesn't overload the operator or doesn't use it in the first place (e.g. for built-in types)

Comment: @CoffeeandCode In order to be able to aply "operator->" it is needed only to define it inside a class, it isn't necessary for the pointer to be smart or dumb or even pointer.

Comment: _"The documentation says..."_ Which documentation would that be?

Comment: 'Special pointer' is not a recognized programming term, that was the whole point of me commenting. I thought he meant smart pointers because he said "i looked up what `shared_ptr` are", though... My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cannot find an example of a real use of it ( unless it is used to find a linked list last element ).

I think you're misunderstanding what it does. It isn't used to dereference a list element and keep dereferencing the next element. Each time you call `operator->` you would get back a *different type*, the point is that if that second type also has an `operator->` it will be called, which might return a different type again. Imagine it being like `x->->->i` not `x->next->next->next` if that helps

> An example of real world use could help too, as probably I am missing a model where to apply the behaviour.

It can be useful for the [Execute Around Pointer](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Execute-Around_Pointer) pattern.

> On the opposite side there could be the need to avoid that behaviour, how could it be done ?

Call the operator explicitly:

```
auto x = p.operator->();
```

Answer (score 7):

Well, the `->` operator works under rater special circumstances.

One can call it a pseudo-binary operator. According to its natural syntax `pointer->member` it takes two operands: a normal run-time operand on the left-hand side and a rather "strange" *member name* operand on the right-hand side. The "strangeness" of the second operand is rooted in the fact that C++ language has no user-accessible concept for representing such operands. There's nothing in the language that would express a *member name* as an operand. There's no way to "pass" a member name through the code to the user-defined implementation. The member name is a compile-time entity, remotely similar to constant expressions in that regard, but no constant expression in C++ can specify members. (There are expressions for pointers-to-members, but not for members themselves).

This creates rather obvious difficulties in specifying the behavior of overloaded `->` operator: how do we connect what was specified on the right-hand side of `->` (i.e the member name) to the code written by the user? It is not possible to do it directly. The only way out of this situation is to do it indirectly: force the user to channel the user-defined functionality of the overloaded `->` operator into the functionality of some existing *built-in* operator. The built-in operator can handle member names naturally, through its core language capabilities.

In this particular case we have only two candidates to channel the functionality of the overloaded `->` to: the built-in `->` and the built-in `.`. It is only logical that the built-in `->` was chosen for that role. This created an interesting side-effect: the possibility to write "chained" (recursive) sequences of overloaded `->` operators (unwrapped implicitly by the compiler) and even infinitely recursive sequences (which are ill-formed).

Informally speaking, every time you use a smart pointer you make a real-world use of these "recursive" properties of overloaded `->` operator. If you have a smart pointer `sptr` that points to a class object with member `member`, the member access syntax remains perfectly natural, e.g. `sptr->member`. You don't have to do it as `sptr->->member` or `sptr->.member` specifically because of the implicit "recursive" properties of overloaded `->`.

Note that this recursive behavior is only applied when you use *operator* syntax for invoking the overloaded `->` operator, i.e. the `object->member` syntax. However, you can also use the regular member function call syntax to call your overloaded `->`, e.g. `object.operator ->()`. In this case the call is carried out as an ordinary function call and no recursive application of `->` takes place. This is the only way to avoid the recursive behavior. If you implement overloaded `->` operator whose return type does not support further applications of `->` operator (for example, you can define an overloaded `->` that returns `int`), then the `object.operator ->()` will be the only way to invoke your overloaded implementation. Any attempts to use the `object->member` syntax will be ill-formed.

Comment: There are pointers to members so somehow the "member" concept is accessible to the programmer too.

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis, but when the right operand is a pointer to member you have to say `x->*pmf` not `x->name` so it's not accessible using `operator->`

Comment: @George Kourtis: Yes, but in this specific case the difference between a *pointer-to-member* and a *member itself* is of critical importance. We have a completely different operator `->*` for working with pointers-to-members, and that one is indeed a regular binary operator. It is possible to make it a regular binary operator specifically because the language has the concept for representing pointers-to-members.